# Custom positioning popups in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[image: I want to add pop ups right above these buttons where the arrows are pointing]

I am not sure how to position popups at this location. In the documentation examples, it states to use the id of the popup div in the href of where the popup should occur.

example:

```
<a href="#popupPadded" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Popup with padding</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupPadded" class="ui-content">
  <p>This is a popup with the <code>ui-content</code> class added to the popup container.</p>
</div>
```

But my partial view is being used somewhere else with href="#". How can I position my popups in the partial view and also reuse them on other pages?

Here is the HTML for my partial view:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red"  data-position-to="origin"    data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_CS" style="pointer-events: none;">CS</a>    
<a href="#" data-icon="GhCsStatus-Red"  data-position-to="origin"    data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" id="GhCsStatus_GH" style="pointer-events: none;">GH</a>

<div id="GH_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Get History is OFF! </p>
</div>

<div id="CS_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Communication Service is OFF! </p>
</div>      

<div id="GHCS_popup" data-role="popup">
<p> Get History and Communication Service are OFF! </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use custom tool tips, instead of popups? Btw, JQM 1.4 has a tooltip widget. Or you can create your own without the need to use JQM 1.4 as it's in beta phase.

Comment: @Omar If you are talking about jQuery UI, I don't know if I should add another library to this project. I can;t seem to find JQM tooltip widget. Thank you for your input!

Comment: You don't need any extra libraries. With a bit of CSS and jq, you can make your own tooltips. I feel bad that my previous answer didn't resolve your problem, you made me feel guilty :/

Comment: @Omar haha no worries! Things came up and I wasn't able to work on it during that time! I should have worked on it promptly but things came up! I appreciated your help!

Comment: I don't really know CSS either haha it makes it a bit hard on me. gotta learn it =/

Comment: Haha..don't worry, I can help you out. Tomorrow wil work on a tooltip for you :)

Comment: @Omar Oh yea the reason why I chose popups is because I have logic running in the back around revolving around SQL so depending on my data changes, the popup will appear or not. But you if believe I do not need to use pop ups I'd be happy to look at what you suggest!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38765/discussion-between-omar-and-liondancer)